# Bluetooth Head Phones not providing stereo sound

Tags: sound, bluetooth, alsa

Ive recently switched to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 10.1.
Now i have an Audionic [B333](http://www.audionic.co/product/bluebeats-b333) bluetooth stereo head phone that worked perfectly in windows 10.1 but in ubuntu it is only providing mono sound.

Can any one help me with that?